# What are the adequacy conditions for Rosser Provability?

Tags: lo.logic, peano-arithmetic

Famously, Rosser introduced a provability predicate $\pi[A]$ that holds iff $\exists x(xP[A]\wedge\forall y(y\le x\to\lnot yP[\lnot A]))$.

Supposing $PA$ is consistent, what are the adequacy conditions for $\pi$ as compared with the Hilbert-Bernays-Löb derivability conditions for P?

In particular, do we have $\vdash_{PA}\pi[A]\Leftrightarrow\hspace{2pt}\vdash_{PA}A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that PA is consistent, then the two provability predicates are equivalent, since Rosser provability implies regular provability; and conversely, if there is a proof of $A$ in PA, then by Con(PA) there will be no proof of $\neg A$ at all, let alone one with a shorter proof, and so $A$ is Rosser provable. Thus, PA+Con(PA) proves that $\pi[A]\iff P[A]$. The point is that the Rosser provability predicate becomes  more interesting when the theory is inconsistent.

Your final query, however, is a bit different from this equivalence. Nevertheless, that biconditional happens also to be true (arguing in ZFC, say, but it suffices merely that PA is sufficiently sound). Namely, if PA proves $\pi[A]$, then $\pi[A]$ is true, and so there really is a proof of $A$. Conversely, if $A$ is provable in PA, then there will be a specific proof of $A$, and by Con(PA) there is no shorter proof of $\neg A$, and so PA will prove $\pi[A]$.

Perhaps the proof theorists will say exactly what one needs to undertake that argument.

Comment: Will it be correct to say that $if$ PA is consistent then $\vdash_{PA}A\Leftrightarrow\hspace{2pt}\vdash_{PA}\hspace{-1pt}\pi[A]$?

Comment: I now see that my last question was addressed at the end of your answer; I was confused by your use of $\iff$ for the object language material conditional.

Comment: So here is my translation of your take on my last question into my own occasional lingo:

If PA is consistent and only proves true arithmetical sentences then $\vdash_{PA}A\Leftrightarrow\hspace{2pt}\vdash_{PA}\pi[A]$.  

Is my lingo satisfactory?

Comment: I guess what we need is that PA is $\Pi^0_1$-sound, since from $PA$ proving $\pi[A]$, we want to know that there really is a proof of $A$.

Comment: I appreciate that weakening; so if PA is consistent and $\Pi^0_1$-sound then $\vdash_{PA}A\Leftrightarrow\hspace{2pt}\vdash_{PA}\pi[A]$.

Comment: Are the other Hilbert-Bernays-Löb derivability conditions unaffected?

Comment: If PA is $\Pi^0_1$-sound, then Con(PA) is true, since otherwise, it would prove everything, including false $\Pi^0_1$ sentences.

Comment: But $\pi[A]$ is $\Sigma^0_1$, right? So why is it not $\Sigma^0_1$-soundness we need in order to conclude from $PA$ proving $\pi[A]$ that there really is a proof in $PA$ of $A$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is $\Sigma^0_1$-soundness that I want.

Comment: If I recall correctly, PA is $\Sigma^0_1$-complete; does that not affect the situation here?

It seems that if PA is $\Sigma^0_1$-complete then PA is $\Sigma^0_1$-sound if $PA$ is consistent.

Comment: PA does prove all true existentials, yes. But the last remark is not quite right. It is correct that $\Sigma^0_1$-soundness implies consistency, since if the theory is inconsistent, then it proves everything, including false statements of that complexity; but this amount of soundness is not necessarily equivalent to consistency, since one can have a model of PA+Con(PA)+$\neg$Con(PA+Con(PA)), and in this model, PA is consistent, but not $\Sigma^0_1$-sound, because this model thinks that PA proves that Con(PA) implies 0=1, which is a $\Sigma^0_1$-assertion, but it isn't true in this model.

Comment: Meanwhile, Con(PA) is equivalent to $\Pi^0_1$-soundness, because soundness implies consistency, and conversely, if PA is not $\Pi^0_1$-sound, then it proves a false $\Pi^0_1$ sentence; but the negation is a true existential, which PA also proves, giving inconsistency.

Comment: I also meanwhile realized that my previous statement is false.

At any rate, there must be some other aspect of adequacy for $\pi$ that is operative in Rosser's argument as it does not according to the lore appeal to $\Sigma^0_1$-soundness.

Comment: Sorry, I don't chat on MO.

Comment: I deleted some quite erroneous and so also overtly misleading comments.

It seems clear to me now that Rosser shows that one only needs $\vdash A\Rightarrow\hspace{2pt}\vdash\pi[A]$ + the assumption of consistency to produce the incompleteness. I believe that one needs to appeal to 1-consistency to justify $\vdash A\Leftarrow\hspace{2pt}\vdash\pi[A]$. But $PA$ is probably 1-consistent.